# Add and Delete CoreData based on attribute value search match

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

Setup: iOS 9, Swift, XCODE 7.1 Beta

Goal is to build shopping cart functionally for which I need unique values in CoreData.

I have a UITableView in which data (Product name, Cost, Quantity, ID) is uploaded from Parse backend. Each TableView custom cell has a button, tapping which saves the selected row data in CoreData.

I don't want to have duplicate product in the cart, so before saving I want to check if the cart already have the product. If it has, I want to replace the cart with currently selected data. If not, just want to add a new product in the cart.

My CoreData setup is simple.

> Entity name = Cart
>
> Attributes = pName(type String), pCost(type
> Int), pQuantity(type Int), orderID(type String)

Add product to the Cart button code is as below:

```
// Product data is retrieved in these variable
var pNam = NSMutableArray()
var pCost = NSMutableArray()
var pQty = NSMutableArray()
var pObjectID = NSMutableArray()

// Add to Cart button ....
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ProductMenuTableViewCell! // Custom cell in which the button add to Cart button is placed 

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let cart = Cart(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        
        cart.pName = pNam[indexPath.row].description
        cart.pCost = pCst[indexPath.row].integerValue!
        cart.pQuantity = pQty[indexPath.row].integerValue!
        cart.orderID = pObjectID[indexPath.row].description
        
        var error: NSError?
        
        do {
            try managedObjectContext?.save()
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
        }
        
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedFailureReason)
        } else {
            print("Saved")
        }
```

Should I directly use cell to add values to CoreData? For ex: `cart.pName = cell.pName.text!` or there is a better way to do it? Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your data setup is absurd. You have 4 arrays for the 4 attributes of `n` objects. If for any reason the sorting of an array changes, or an element is dropped or added, you have to make sure the same happens with all the other arrays, a maintenance nightmare! How do you expand this model if later you have 15 attributes. Use 15 arrays? This is completely crazy.

Instead, you should have an array of objects - ideally Core Data objects - with the appropriate attributes grouped together. You can always keep a flag to indicate that you want to discard these items later rather then persist them in the database.

Now you do not have to decide to create or update: simply set the delete flag to `false`.

Comment: Can you please share a link? or a sample code? I am still new in programming and core data is completely new to me. I did thought about the array option for the same reason you suggested, but I was not able to see Array type in Attributes. At this moment, I can make things work, but it will be a long learning curve to know the right way to make things work in programming world. Thank you for your valuable suggestion. This really helps.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is beyond the scope of this question. Maybe the best advise would be to do something simpler first if you are new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for an existing Cart object with the correct name; if there is no matching Cart, then create a new one.  Something like this:

```
    var cart : Cart
    let requiredName = pNam[indexPath.row].description
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription!
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"pName == %@",requiredName)
    do {
        let results = try self.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Cart]
        if results.count == 0 { // not found, so create new...
            cart = Cart(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
            cart.pName = requiredName
        } else { // found at least one, so use the first...
            cart = results[0]
        }
        // Now update the other attribute values:
        cart.pCost = pCst[indexPath.row].integerValue!
        cart.pQuantity = pQty[indexPath.row].integerValue!
        cart.orderID = pObjectID[indexPath.row].description
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching")
    }
```

Regarding your secondary question, personally I would use your current approach: use the row as an index on your dataSource arrays, i.e. don't directly use the values from the cell's labels etc.

Comment: Can you please tell me why indexPath method is better than using the cell's labels method? Any pros/cons? Thanks for the code, I will check it soon and update.

Comment: @VickyArora In practice, I am sure using cell labels can be made to work, but I think it is slightly out of line with Apple's Model-View-Controller design pattern (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1)).  An example of what could go wrong: suppose you later want to produce an internationalised version of your app.  The labels would all need to be translated, whereas your data might remain in the base language.  You would need to "untranslate" the labels in the above code.